# How do i unscrew this screw to take apart the bed frame

Tags: screws

I have a broken bed that I need to take apart to haul it to junk. How do i unscrew the screw in the picture? THere are several screws like that in the bed frame.
[image: screw in bed frame]

Comment: Do you think you can get a better picture of it? Also, knowing what the bed frame is (manufacturer and model name) could help.

Comment: Look close, is the small center hole hexagonal, to accept a hex wrench?

Comment: And if it's not hexagonal, are the six bits around the outside of the hole recessed, so you could jam a slightly open set of needle-nosed pliers in there and turn the fastener?

Comment: If you're going to junk it, you could just unscrew it with a hammer. ;) Take it outside or lay down some floor protection and go nuts. It looks like press-board; it'll snap in half if you even look at it funny.

Comment: Thanks. I have put a followup here http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106144/how-to-repair-broken-bed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a cam lock which holds onto the head of a bolt in the plane of the wooden piece. Ikea furniture is fastened this way. Turn it counter clockwise to a stop and it will release the bolt.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you're on the wrong side.  The center is the wrong end of a machine screw.  The perimeter is a pressed-in nut.

Look on the other side, I bet you'll find the screw head.